# How to determine whether or not user sent MS Outlook message which had builded from Java code?

Tags: java

In my Java program I create Outlook.exe process and send message with pre-populated content. After sending the message or closing message window I need to know whether or not the user sent the  message.

In Java code `exitValue()` method of process doesn't help because `exitValue` in both cases is 0.

What can I do?

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
Process process = processBuilder.command("C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\OUTLOOK.exe", "/a").start();
if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
    Session session = sessionExtracting();
    session.beginTransaction();
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("UPDATE mailorder set mailordstatus = 2");
    query.executeUpdate();
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: Unless a program add identification measures into the email itself want is not possible.  An email is plain text, its not possible to tell if a machine or a human created an email, unless its obvious (or identified) by the content itself.  We cannot help you with programming questions.

Comment: Deliberate duplicate of an identical post from the author from earlier on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not the way Microsoft applications work. Starting a command and testing its return code is common in the Unix world. But in Windows, automatization is expected to use Microsoft's specific automation systems such as DDE (now legacy), COM/DCOM or .NET. The last two allows a controlling program to create an *object* that knows how to manage the application. Using COM or .NET is trivial in VisualBasic, easy in C# (for .NET), and possible in C++. PowerShell also allows to control application through their .NET interfaces.

So here are your options:

- use a Microsoft language or a PowerShell script to create a program that sends a mail via Outlook **and sets a return code**, and start that *proxy* program from Java
- build a class that uses a .NET bridge to control Outlook. Google has told me that there are either commercial solutions like [JNBridge](http://jnbridge.com/) or free ones like [jni4net](http://jni4net.com/index.html) - disclaimer, I have never used either...